# Special symbols on objects names dont let me navigate trough objects/arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, object, object-properties

Right now, im using drupal for making a site. Im modifying the drupals user module, because i need to make a custom layout for the profile page.

Unfortenly im having issues for accessing trough the array.

all the data of the profile is on an array ($user_profile)

The array is just HUGE. im trying to navigate trough the objects.

While im doing a good job navigating (thanks to the print_r function), im facing a problem right now.

there's an object called entityInfo:protected. Inside this object there's more objects (by example, im trying to access to the object that is inside of this object, called label.

the issue is, if i try to do this:

```
echo $user_profile['profile_medico']['view']['profile2']['2']['field_tags']['#object']->{'entityInfo:protected'}->label
```

I get the next message

**Notice: Undefined property: Profile::$entityInfo:protected in include() (line 55 of D:\xampp\htdocs\specialdr\modules\user\user-profile.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 55 of D:\xampp\htdocs\specialdr\modules\user\user-profile.tpl.php).**

I dont know how can i write this correctly so i can access to this object and keep going trough the arrays and objects... because i still have a loong way until i get to the objects i need to access.

By the way... if you want to see the array... http://fancomix.net/bigarray.txt

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply `->entityInfo`, `:protected` is not needed, it is an access modifier or visibility modifier. It is only displayed in the `var_dump()` to provide information about the property. An object property (and method also) can be declared either public, protected or private in PHP. You can read more about [Visibility in the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

`protected` means the property can only be accessed from an object method - no outside access, so you won't be able to get the property. The `Profile` class can have a getter method though - you should inspect the definition of that class to find it, or make necessary changes if you can, like changing it to `public` or writing a getter method.

Comment: HI, thanks for your quick answer and indeed that was the issue!.
Now, unfortenly, when i try to load something inside from this object it gives me a fatal error. 

"Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property Profile::$entityInfo in D:\xampp\htdocs\specialdr\modules\user\user-profile.tpl.php on line 57"

Im sorry, im trying to understand with the link you gave me but i hope you could help me with this... Again... Thanks!

Comment: @EgEm Well, yeah. Forgot to mention that a protected property cannot be read from outside the object, only object methods can access it.

Comment: Thank you so much!, i finally manage to understand my issue... and in the end, i verified and the Location of the info i needed wasnt inside of the EntityInfo Object... It was OUTSIDE! DAH DX... But hey, thank you, now i know something new, and i need to check more about "objects" and all that stuff. Thanks!